# % of Total group by count of other column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, percentage

I want to get the % of total Sales from items with multiple purchase record in mysql. Thanks in advance.

My table

```
ItemId | SalesAmt
-------+---------
X1000  | 50  
X1000  | 200  
X1001  | 150
```

Desired Result

```
itemType | Sales_pct
---------+----------
multip   | 0.75  
single   | 0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select itemtype, sum(amt) / sum(sum(amt)) over() sales_ratio
from (
    select 
        case when count(*) > 1 then 'mutiple' else 'single' end itemtype,
        sum(amt) amt
    from mytable
    group by itemid
) t
group by itemtype
```

Answer (score 0):

The @GMB solution uses `window function` so can not be used in MySQL 5.*.
Below solutions for MySQL 5.*:

```
select 
    sum(if(cnt = 1, amnt, null)) / sum(amnt) as single, 
    sum(if(cnt = 1, null, amnt)) / sum(amnt) as multiple
from (
    select ItemId, count(*) cnt, sum(SalesAmt) amnt from test group by ItemId
) t;
```

Here the [fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=75a6c68b8622a6af5cd1a8d697563f9f&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

**Result**:

```
single | multiple
-------+---------
0.3750 |   0.6250
```

Comment: If the output fails to match the desired result then I'd be tempted to suggest that there's something wrong somewhere